# How do I get certain part of object as string

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to get data from a server depends on logged in user's name.

I succeed to get correct object, but I failed to get only certain part of it.

```
getDepartmentByEmp : function (){
    var empName = $.trim($(".temp-test").html());
    console.log(empName);
    $.ajax({
        contentType : "application/json",
        dataType : 'json',
        type : "GET",
        url : "<c:url value='/app/general/add/getDepartment/'/>" + empName,
        complete : function(data) {
            $("#docDepartment").val(data.responseText);
            $("#docDepartment").prev().html(data.responseText);
            console.log(data.responseText);
            console.log(typeof data.responseText);
        }
    });
},
```

That empName gets each logged in users' empNameTrim value in my DB.
The type of data is object and responseText is string.

And its output looks like following:

[image]

[image]

[image]

I want to make the value of docDepartment equals to the value of department which will be SM in this case.

Thank you in advance.

**EDIT**: I followed Loïc Faure-Lacroix's tips, modified my code like following:

**1st**

```
getDepartmentByEmp : function (){
    var empName = $.trim($(".temp-test").html());
    console.log(empName);
    $.ajax({
        contentType : "application/json",
        dataType : 'json',
        type : "GET",
        url : "<c:url value='/app/general/add/getDepartment/'/>" + empName,
        complete : function(data) {
            var doc = JSON.parse(data.responseText);
            $("#docDepartment").val(doc.department);
            $("#docDepartment").prev().html(doc.department);
            console.log(doc.department);
            console.log(typeof doc.department);
        }
    });
},
```

**2nd**

```
getDepartmentByEmp : function (){
    var empName = $.trim($(".temp-test").html());
    console.log(empName);
    $.ajax({
        contentType : "application/json",
        dataType : 'json',
        type : "GET",
        url : "<c:url value='/app/general/add/getDepartment/'/>" + empName,
        complete : function(data) {
            $("#docDepartment").val(data.responseJSON.department);
            $("#docDepartment").prev().html(data.responseJSON.department);
            console.log(data.responseJSON.department);
            console.log(typeof data.responseJSON.department);
        }
    });
},
```

**3rd**

```
getDepartmentByEmp : function (){
    var empName = $.trim($(".temp-test").html());
    console.log(empName);
    $.ajax({
        contentType : "application/json",
        dataType : 'json',
        type : "GET",
        url : "<c:url value='/app/general/add/getDepartment/'/>" + empName,
    })
    .done(function (data) {
        $("#docDepartment").val(data.department);
        $("#docDepartment").prev().html(data.department);
        console.log(data.department);
        console.log(typeof data.department);
    })
},
```

All of them works fine.  Choose whatever you like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If jQuery isn't parsing to JSON, use `JSON.parse` to do it on the responseText... That said, according to the documentation [here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/), if you go to the data types section, you should read the following:

> If json is specified, the response is parsed using jQuery.parseJSON
>   before being passed, as an object, to the success handler. The parsed
>   JSON object is made available through the responseJSON property of the
>   jqXHR object.

So you should be using this:

```
$("#docDepartment").val(data.responseJSON.department)
```

But to make your code cleaner, It might be better to use the following form:

```
getDepartmentByEmp : function (){
    var empName = $.trim($(".temp-test").html());
    console.log(empName);
    var request = $.ajax({
        contentType : "application/json",
        dataType : 'json',
        type : "GET",
        url : "<c:url value='/app/general/add/getDepartment/'/>" + empName,
    })
    request.done(function (data) {
      $("#docDepartment").val(data.department);
      $("#docDepartment").prev().html(data);
      console.log(data);
      console.log(typeof data);
    })
    request.fail(function () {
       ...
    })
},
```

The main difference is that the `done` callback should be called with the final data. While the `complete` one is called with a `jqXHR` object. It will get called only on success while `complete` is always called even on errors.

Comment: `dataType : 'json',` in `$.ajax()`

Comment: well, your first suggestion already worked lol.  I will try your second one too.

Comment: I know both works, but the second one actually split the error handling while the first one will fail if the http request fails and your app might not work as expected because there is no error handling.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you need to parse the JSON object. I believe jQuery makes your response JSON automagically. So, the following should work for you.

```
 $("#docDepartment").val(data.responseText.department);
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but unfortunately, it only gives me undefined value and type.  I tried data.department, data.department.responseText too, but it still give me same results